# How to use functional operator in maple

Tags: function, maple

I need to understand how the functional operator works on Maple.  Here are some examples of how I tried to tackle the problem (with the help of others).

```
ee := [r*x(1-x)];
eval(ee,[x]=~[x]);
eval(ee,[x]=~eval(ee,[x]=~[x])); ## Example 1

ff := x-> r*x(1-x);
ff(x);
ff(r*x(1-x));                    ## Example 2
```

and finally

```
subs(x=x,r*x(1-x));
subs(x=r*x(1-x),r*x(1-x));       ## Example 3
```

The idea is a function of a function applied many times. Something like `Nest[f,x,10]` in Mathematica.

I would like to understand why the first two examples give the same result but different from the third one.  I am definitely missing something.

I am running Maple 18 on Mac.

Comment: I do not think you are missing anything. `is(ff(r*x(1-x))=subs(x=r*x(1-x),r*x(1-x)));` returns `true` as expected. And `op(eval(ee,[x]=~eval(ee,[x]=~[x]));` also gives the same answer, as you noted. Maple does just not reduce the expressions the same. This is usually a good place to use the `simplify` functional, to make Maple try the same reduction algorithms.

Comment: @therkel.   Many thanks.   I have noticed that there is a difference between r*x(1-x) and r*x*(1-x) at least in Maple 18.  If I retype the examples above using the latter, all the answers are exactly the same. Now (ff@@3)(x) seems to be ok.

Comment: Indeed Maple does not assume implicit multiplication signs and fortunately so for all but for those who are unaware of it. I apologize I did not catch your missing multiplication asterisks.

Comment: I see that you asked a similar Question on MaplePrimes: "Functional operator within a proc." I just wrote a procedure to efficiently and with the greatest possible generality handle all cases of multivariate functional iteration, both numeric and symbolic. Within the hour, I will post it on MaplePrimes as an Answer to the above-mentioned Question. The procedure will simplify at each step, if that's what you want.

Comment: @Carl  Many thanks.   Yes, I wrote a similar question on MaplePrimes.  The question here is more specific so as to help me to understand how Maple works.